# Spring data revision repository: not returning onetomany when using getRevisions

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I have two entity's "Application" and "ApplicationDocument"

Table 1

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "applications")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Application {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Audited
private String title;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "application")
@JsonManagedReference
@AuditJoinTable
private List<ApplicationDocument> applicationDocuments;

}
```

Table 2

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "applicationDocuments")
public class ApplicationDocument {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "applicationid")
@JsonBackReference
@Audited
private Application application;

@Audited
private String file;

}
```

This will create two audit tables, and the data is revisioned every time after insert, update and delete. Works fine till here

But to retrieve revisions

I have a ApplicationRepository which extends springs "RevisionRepository"

So when I fetch something like applicationRepository.getRevisions({{myApplicationId}}). Then when I look at revision entities returned, the one to many relation is always returned as null.

I would expect it to return a list with whatever ApplicationDocuments existed during that revision time.

Any ideas what am I missing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is in the mapping for `Application`.

While both entities are being audited by Envers because they contain at least one `@Audited` non-id attribute, the inverse side of the collection in `Application` is not being audited.  In short, Envers ignores the attribute because `@AuditJoinTable` by itself doesn't trigger the attribute to be included in the audit metadata.

You need to change your `Application` entity so that the collection is mapped as follows

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "application")
@Audited
@AuditJoinTable
private List<ApplicationDocument> applicationDocuments;
```

A shortcut to remember is that if all attributes of an entity are to be audited by Envers, you can instead annotate the actual class with `@Audited` to minimize the verbosity if that helps and you would have avoided having this problem too :).

Comment: Excellent thanks for explaining, Yes I can use "Audited" on class, but my real entities have loads of other properties which I am not auditing.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying out spring-data-envers at the moment and I assume you have this lib on your classpath as well. So you get the EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl under the hood, which uses the Envers AuditReader API to fetch the revision information. Relations in the returned Hibernate Proxies by this API aren´t initialized, regardless of what is specified in the JPA relationship annotations. So any OneToOne, OneToMany etc. isn´t loaded even if set to eager or eager by default.

There are bugs/feature request regarding this problem e.g.

[Eagerly load collections when indicated so in the annotation defining the relation](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3552)

[Allow specifying join fetches through the AuditQuery API](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11479)

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with eager/lazy but the fact the audit mappings are incorrect, see my answer for details.

Comment: @Naros The mappings are incorrect, that is the real problem ok. Just to get this right for me, but it is true that the entities returned are proxies and the OneToMany relation is always lazy loaded? krishna somehow retrieves the ApplicationDocuments inside the PersistenceContext after calling findRevisions(ID) on the RevisionRepository, am i right? There is still no way to fetch them together with the Application entities?

Comment: That part is accurate, collections are lazily loaded when first accessed via a proxy that Envers uses to wrap the collection's initialization.  The issues you reference are improvements to that process that I'd like to investigate long-term.